# How to differentiate between two types of status changes?

Tags: info-visualisation, data-tables, actions, status

We have several rows of data (in a CMS) that change in status. There are two types of status changes: type 1 requires action from Admin but type 2 doesn't.

My issue is differentiating between the two types of status changes. Currently, when it's a type 1 status change, we highlight the row. If it's type 2, the row just remains grey.

Should we cater for the type 2 status change also? Giving some indication that the row has changed in status recently but doesn't require action? If so, how do we ensure that it's not confusing (i.e. there are too many status change indicators)?

[image]

Comment: could you elaborate Status change scenario

Comment: Do Admins need to know which rows "had changed in status recently but doesn't require action"? Is it part of their task having to know these?

Comment: Some information about the type of status would also be useful. For example, are these two types of statuses equivalent or completely different in terms of the change or action required.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's not a good idea to use color as the only differentiating factor to display the status. It's better to use an icon and/or text to highlight this. Color-only differentiation looks clean, but is not not great for accessibility, and can cause issues with brand/theme colors. Especially for broader application and diverse groups of users.

There are some other scenarios you could try:

- Perhaps you could split the list into 2 levels with a clear divider:

  1. These require actions
  2. Don't require actions

[image]

- You could use a 'focus' view of the list that basically filters the entire list just on items that require actions 
  Like this: [image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all way do you show the list item which do not require the action item?

Populating both together would increase the effort for finding the list item which needs the action to be taken.

Ways of handling the items which does not require the action to be taken

- Hide the list item which does not require the action
- Provide the filter to group different status items
- if the list need to be show upfront, segregate / group the items in tabs. On click on status time the list of items loads.
- If the condition is to show all at once, then have a sort option

Hope this would help you